How to play (Create(mobject)) that is being updated dynamically?
phase = ValueTracker(0)
        def waver(phase, dt):
            phase.set_value(phase.get_value() - dt)
        phase.add_updater(waver)
        graph = always_redraw(
            lambda: ax.plot(
            lambda x: self.gassian(x, -1.25, 0.3)*self.osc(x, 15, phase.get_value()),
            stroke_width = 1,
            color=BLUE
            )
        )
        self.add(phase)
        phase.update()
        self.wait()
        self.play(Create(ax.x_axis), Create(graph), run_time=1)

This first creates the graph. And then abruptly starts incrementing the angle 'phi'
I want to increment the angle 'phi' even while creating. How do I do it?
I tried manually calling update(). Added self.wait() to give it some time. And added phase to scene. But it doesn't work.
